# Testing URL schemes with try/catch

Tags: javascript, try-catch, url-scheme

I'm trying to test URL schemes via javascript try/catch blocks but my catch blocks are not being executed. Safari just skips them entirely and I don't understand why?!

```
function open_twitter() {
        if (!IS_IOS){ //made unequal IOS so that I could test it on my Macbook
          try {
            window.location = "twitter://"; //fails and should go to the catch block
          } catch (e) { //skipped
            try { //skipped
              window.location = TWITTERRIFIC_URL_SCHEME; //skipped
            } catch (e) { //skipped
              null; //skipped
            } //skipped
          } //skipped
        } else {
          window.open(TWITTER_URL, "_blank");
        }
      }
```

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening?

I want the code to test the first URL scheme. If that isn't successful than it should (in theory) go to the catch block and run the code inside which is in my case a try block again with the next URL scheme to test and so on and so forth.
But this doesn't happen?! I'm really confused...

Comment: setting the page's url navigates the page, why would it throw an error? use location.href to navigate more reliably...

Comment: Thanks. Still no solution for my problem. All these methods are fire & forget.

Comment: And it should throw an error if the app is not installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try catch doesn't work exactly like what you wrote, You'll need to provide your catch with an exception, Else it doesn't know something bad happened.

See these docs : `https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch`

try/catch should be used as a simple test with your custom exception. For example,

```
try
{
if(false==false)
{
    throw "myException"; // generates an exception
}
catch (e) {
   // statements to handle any exceptions
   logMyErrors(e); // pass exception object to error handler
}
```

As you can see, The try should test for something and return an exception if some condition is met.

Comment: But how does the `if(false == false)` know if its false or not?

Comment: Well youll need a condition to test, it could be any logical test. Thats how i always used it